# Multiple filters with camanjs don't work

Tags: jquery, filter, brightness, contrast, camanjs

I have an image, and I want to apply brightness and contrast on the same image. If I simply apply brightness, but if I apply with contrast, it does not work; the image turns black.
I have tried with layers; it didn't work.
I have tried to render in layer, and then, render after it; it also didn't work.
I have tried to render each filter; same thing.
I have tried first to simply apply contrast, and then to apply brightness; the image turns grey.
I have tried this.revert() and this.revert(false).Nope.

What am I doing wrong? I want to make like on the examples section on their website: http://camanjs.com/examples/
 PS, the values for brightness and contrast are from two range inputs.

The code is:

```js
$('#brightI,#contrastI').on('input change', function(){

   var bright= document.getElementById("brightI").value;
   var contrast= document.getElementById("contrastI").value;

   $('#brightnessValue').text(bright);
   $('#contrastValue').text(contrast);
        Caman("#test", function () {
            this.revert(false);
            this.contrast(contrast);
             this.newLayer(function () 
             {
                this.setBlendingMode('multiply');
                 this.copyParent();
                 this.filter.brightness(bright);
            })
      this.render();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code.

```
$('#brightI,#contrastI').on('change', function(){
   var bright= document.getElementById("brightI").val();
   var contrast= document.getElementById("contrastI").val();

   $('#brightnessValue').val(bright);
   $('#contrastValue').val(contrast);
        Caman("#test", function () {
            this.revert(false);
            this.contrast(contrast);
             this.newLayer(function () 
             {
                this.setBlendingMode('multiply');
                 this.copyParent();
                 this.filter.brightness(bright);
            })
      this.render();
});
});
```

I did change a binding event and "text" changed to val()  ( u can use .html() in another elements "not inputs" )

```
.on('input change', function(){
.on('change', function(){
```

i didn't seen never "input" event :) good luck